# Cakephp regarding Security Component and CSRF protection

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

There seems to be a problem with Security component when enabled, I cannot get my AJAX to work on the same controller where it is enabled!

I'm getting below error:

```
The Request has Been Blackholed
```

Is there a way to ensure AJAX is actually working with POST requests with Security Component enabled?

I do not want to create another AJAX controller just for this

Thanks

Comment: You can disable Security component temporarily if the request is an ajax one.

Comment: OK thank you but how do you do this? I tried SecurityComponent::$csrfCheck "false" in a controller function but it doesn't work

Comment: It has to be done in beforeFilter

Comment: I did it in beforeFilter but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

 class AppController extends Controller {

 public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = 'blackhole';
   }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it simply pushes everything that is blackholed to a given action, opening up a hard-to-debug security loophole.